# Maximum number of points on a grid with no three of them being collinear

Tags: geometry, number-theory

What is the maximum number of points $GP(N)$ you can have with no three points being collinear, when the points are taken from a $N \times N$ grid?

Examples:

$GP(0) = 0$

```
(empty)
```

$GP(1) = 1$

```
X
```

$GP(2) = 4$

```
XX
XX
```

$GP(3) = 6$

```
XXO
XOX
OXX
```

Comment: Do you have a guess for GP(4) (or a few higher)?

Comment: An easy upper limit is $2n$ because you can have at most two per row.  I suspect there is enough room to achieve this, but have not tried.

Comment: My guess for GP(4) is 8... I could write a short script to find the correct answer, however I'm intrigued about the mathematics of it.